# Python Subprocess.Popen notification with sound alarm

Tags: python

I am trying to create a desktop notification with alarm sound. I am using linux system. 
I could create desktop notification, but no sound. Can you please help me to add an alarm during notification.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(['notify-send', 'MyFunction', '-i', '/home/my_data/Documents/My_GUI/Icons/Logo.png', 'Done!'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using below code and pass the notification sound file name.

```
stop_sound = False
while not stop_sound:
     process = subprocess.Popen(["afplay", "beep.wav"], shell=False)
     if stop_sound:
         process.kill()
```

Comment: I tried this in my OS, linux mint. I have used the .org file given in the system, /usr/share/cinnamon/applets/notifications@cinnamon.org. But it doesn't work, seems afplay is not working with .org